# Test Isjson in MXUnit

Tags: json, testing, coldfusion, testcase, mxunit

I am working on the MxUnit test frame work for CFML. In it, I want to check whether the return value of a function is a valid JSON or not. Currently I am using:

```
assertEquals(True,IsJSON(userEventItems),'The return must be json');
```

Is there any MXUnit function to check the assert is a JSON or not, like `assertIsQuery()` in MXUnit?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [MXUnit built-in assertions](http://wiki.mxunit.org/display/default/Built-In+Assertions) page there is not a function. Your best bet is to test the function the way you are or by using the `assertTrue()` function

```
assertTrue(isJSON(userEventItems), 'The return must be json');
```